# way around the if loops.. actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, if-statement

I am making a choice based game.. where I have given the user different objects each time and ones that they click gets a specific value....

this is where the problem comes in when I have to export this into showing their choices I have to write an if statement for everysingle object asking to check it's value.. if it's the one user picked then draw the object on to the stage.. now this gets really messy does anybody know a way around this? can u please explain it to me step by step since I am fairly new at this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how many different items you have, you might be able to save a bitmask, like this:

```
 items = 00001101110011
```

Where 1 represents an item the user has, and 0 one they don't have.

Then, you just need one loop, iterating `i`, and then check if `(1<<i) & items` and get the item's data from an array.

Comment: oh k... can u elaborate on that please I don't have a lot of knowledge of arrays.. though I know what they are used for.. can u give me an example please?

Comment: The idea here is sound, don't interrogate all the objects for their value in some giant if statement. Instead when the user makes a choice, you record their choice somehow. @kolink is suggesting using bits, but if that is too complicated, use some other type of data structure to save their choices.  I don't know why this answer was down voted. You should make an effort to try this and show your code, and I'm sure someone will be glad to help :)